# Optaplanner: prevent custom List from beeing cloned by FieldAccessingSolutionCloner

Tags: optaplanner

I have a `@PlanningSolution` class, that has one field with a custom `List` implementation as type.
When solving I run into the following issue (as described in the optaplanner documentation):

*`java.lang.IllegalStateException`: The cloneCollectionClass (`class java.util.ArrayList`) created for originalCollectionClass (class `Solution$1`) is not assignable to the field's type (`class CustomListImpl`).
Maybe consider replacing the default `SolutionCloner`.*

As this field has no impact on planning, can I prevent `FieldAccessingSolutionCloner` from trying to clone that particular field e.g. by adding some annotation? I dont want to provide a complete custom `SolutionCloner`.

When inspecting the sources of `FieldAccessingSolutionCloner` I found out that I only needed to override the method `retrieveCachedFields(...)` or `constructCloneCollection(...)` so I tried to extend `FieldAccessingSolutionCloner` but then I need a public no-args-constructor. There I dont know how to initialise the field `solutionDescriptor` in the no-args-constructor to use my `ExtendedFieldAccessingSolutionCloner` as solution cloner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the generic solution cloner decided to clone that `List`, there is probably a good reason for it do so: one of the the elements in that list probably has a reference to a planning entity or the planning solution - and therefore the entire list needs to be planning cloned.

If that's not the case, this is a bug in OptaPlanner. Please provide the classes source code of the class with that field and the CustomListImpl class too, so we can reproduce and fix it.

---

To supply a custom `SolutionCloner`, follow the docs which will show something like this (but this is a simple case without chained variables, so it's easy to get right, but solution cloning is notoriously difficult!).

```
@PlanningSolution(solutionCloner = VaccinationSolutionCloner.class)
public class VaccinationSolution {...}


public class VaccinationSolutionCloner implements SolutionCloner<VaccinationSolution> {

    @Override
    public VaccinationSolution cloneSolution(VaccinationSolution solution) {
        List<PersonAssignment> personAssignmentList = solution.getPersonAssignmentList();
        List<PersonAssignment> clonedPersonAssignmentList = new ArrayList<>(personAssignmentList.size());
        for (PersonAssignment personAssignment : personAssignmentList) {
            PersonAssignment clonedPersonAssignment = new PersonAssignment(personAssignment);
            clonedPersonAssignmentList.add(clonedPersonAssignment);
        }
        return new VaccinationSolution(solution.getVaccineTypeList(), solution.getVaccinationCenterList(), solution.getAppointmentList(),
                solution.getVaccinationSlotList(), clonedPersonAssignmentList, solution.getScore());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thx, the problem was that elements in that custom list had (unnecessary) references to planning entities. When i removed the references, the generic cloner stopped cloning it.